# Add custom item data after item name on Woocommerce order emails

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, email-notifications

I'm trying to add some labels after Woocommerce order email items.

Ex- we can do that on cart by using this filer

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', array( $this, 'wc_esd_show_date_cart_page' ), 10, 2 );
```

above call wc_esd_show_date_cart_page() function and show its data after item name

I want to do the same for order email items, anyone know there have some filter for it, or another way to do this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The very similar hook for orders and email notifications is [`woocommerce_order_item_name`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=woocommerce_order_item_name) filter hook.

But the function arguments are quiet different and you might need to make some changes to your existing function code.

The following will target only email notifications

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', 'wc_esd_show_date_on_order', 10, 3 );
function wc_esd_show_date_on_order( $item_name, $item, $is_visible ) {
    // Only for email notifications
    if( is_wc_endpoint_url() ) 
        return $item_name;

    // ---------------- Your code start below ---------------- //
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, is a way to only add this data to order complete email except other emails

Comment: @SunethKalhara Not using this hook as you can't target in it any specific email notification and you didn't ask that in your initial question.